# apt-get not found in circleci pipeline (ubuntu)

Tags: bash, circleci, circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows

**Objective:** Trying to get public ip of machine via circleci pipeline

**Code I use:**

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  jq: circleci/jq@2.2.0
executors:
  my-executor-terraform:
    docker:
      - image: docker.mirror.hashicorp.services/hashicorp/terraform:light
    working_directory: /home/circleci/workingfile
jobs:
  findpublicip:
    executor: my-executor-terraform
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: get ip to add to azure storage account
          command: |
             apt-get install -y sudo
             sudo apt-get install curl
             ip=$(curl ifconfig.me)
             echo $ip
workflows:
  example-workflow:
    jobs:
      - findpublicip
```

**Error I get:**

```
#!/bin/sh -eo pipefail
apt-get install -y sudo
sudo apt-get install curl
ip=$(curl ifconfig.me)
echo $ip

/bin/sh: apt-get: not found

Exited with code exit status 127
CircleCI received exit code 127
```

VM that circleci uses:

```
Build-agent version 1.0.133815-bc3df9c1 (2022-07-26T23:08:57+0000)
System information:
 Server Version: 20.10.16
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 1
 Kernel Version: 5.13.0-1023-aws
 Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64

Starting container docker.mirror.hashicorp.services/hashicorp/terraform:light
  image is cached as docker.mirror.hashicorp.services/hashicorp/terraform:light, but refreshing...
light: Pulling from hashicorp/terraform
Digest: sha256:7cb0feb2b2c9839830a5be18f266d417bc4619f9eade9a326b019a0886c60a01
Status: Image is up to date for docker.mirror.hashicorp.services/hashicorp/terraform:light
docker.mirror.hashicorp.services/hashicorp/terraform:light:
  using image hashicorp/terraform@sha256:7cb0feb2b2c9839830a5be18f266d417bc4619f9eade9a326b019a0886c60a01
  pull stats: Image was already available so the image was not pulled
  time to create container: 627ms
```

Can you please help to find is missing here ? Circleci using ubuntu based vm to execute the workflow. I tried to install using `apt-get` but it says it dont find `apt-get`

Comment: Wondering if you tried apt instead of apt-get? Also if you know for sure that apt-get is installed, then you likely have an issue with your `$PATH` not set properly. I would check the bash_profile and run `echo $PATH` upon startup to see what's in there. `apt-get` binary should be in `/usr/bin/` & if for some reason you can't fix your path, try running `/usr/bin/apt-get command` as a work around or `/usr/bin/apt`.

Comment: Last suggestion is to use bash instead of sh `#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail` instead of `#!/bin/sh -eo pipefail` ... if possible.

Comment: @paulg I found that, this terraform image is a docker based image then I used apk command to add binaries then it worked. anyhow thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to use `apk add curl` instead of `apt or apg-get` because the runner vm is based on alpine docker image. Hope this helps others facing similar issue to make sure which type of linux flavour you were using